# Hide Object in Render Keyframe Issue Why Does it Apply to other objects?

Tags: rendering, animation, keyframes

So I am trying to hide my cylinder in render for my animation using keyframes, but whenever I try to add a keyframe to hide the cylinder it also hides my plane.

[image]

The Pole "cylinder" is located on it's on file path and the plane is inside a separate collection folder

How on earth is it selecting both the pole and plane to hide on render when I literally only clicked on the cylinder to hide using a keyframe??

Comment: They have the same action, I can see it in the outliner called Dance-3. You can check it in the Action Editor in the Dope Sheet. You can create a new action for one of them there, or unlink the animation data, by select one of them in the 3D viewer then click on Object>>Relations>>Make Single User>>Object Animation.

Comment: @FFeller  where is the make single user option in relations? I only see parent, parent type, tracking and up index

Comment: @FFeller also why would I have to make a new action for each object when it is all part of my same animation?